# Set partitioning with constraints java

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, constraint-programming, integer-programming

**The what**

I'm attempting to produce an optimum set of brackets (optimum defined by constraints) for a tournament.

**The problem**

I don't know how to approach the problem.  [This](https://www.ps.uni-saarland.de/Publications/documents/Mueller_98a.pdf) paper is pretty high level but discusses the possibility of solving set partitioning problems with constraint programming.  It also states that the majority of set partitioning problems are solved via integer programming.  I am mainly looking for an example to emulate.  The question is similar to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759690/optimizing-brackets-for-a-tournament).  The majority of the constraint examples I've seen defined a specific partition total.  Is it possible to model a system where the partitions would be determined dynamically by the  constraints and the participant set? I would link examples but I am limited to only 2 due to my reputation.

**A more concrete example**

**Known values**

- The number of participants is N.
- Each participant has a weight W associated with them.

**Constraints**

- A bracket (set) is made up of 2,3,4,6,7, or 8 participants.
- Each participant is only in a single bracket.
- The must not be more than a 15% difference between the lowest weighted participant and the highest weighted participant in a bracket.
- Favor creating brackets of size 8 and 4 over all other bracket sizes.

So for example say there are 8 participants.

{ {1, W=100}, {2, W=103}, {3, W=105}, {4, W=106}, {5, W=110}, {6, W=114}, {7, W=120}, {8, W=125} }

One possible solution would be:
{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}

A more optimum solution would be:
{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8} since this favors 4, 8 sized sets over the previous solution.

Is it possible to partition a set into a dynamic number of child sets?

Thanks again for your time!

Comment: It would help at least me with some examples of what you are after. Until then, here's a link to some CP models (written in different systems) solving a simple set partition problem: http://www.hakank.org/common_cp_models/#setpartition .

Comment: Hi @hakank,  I've edited my question to hopefully provide you with a better example of what I am looking for.  I looked through your examples and they all seem to be dividing into a predefined number of child sets.  Let me know if I need to elaborate more on my example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a proof-of-concept of a Constraint Programming approach. It's done in MiniZinc, (as usual when I prototyping CSP problems). I haven't implemented it in any Java system but hope it's of some use anyway.

The MiniZinc model is here: http://www.hakank.org/minizinc/bracket_partitioning.mzn

Here's the the principal approach:

- The array ("x") of size 1..N is for assigning the person (x[i]) to which bracket.
  Symmetry breaking on "x":

  - bracket 1 must be used before bracket 2 (the constraint value_precede_chain)
- Another array ("set_size") of 1..N div 2 contains the number of person in each bracket.

  Symmetry breaking on "set_size":

  - The values in "set_size" must be in decreasing order.
- Then there are three help arrays ("mins", "maxs","diffs") of size 1..N div 2 (i.e. the same same as "set_size") which includes the minimum, maximum values of each bracket, and also the difference (diff[s]) between maxs[s]-mins[s]. This difference must be within 15% (calculated as "10000*diffs[s] div maxs[s] <= 1500").

  This 15% requirement is what makes the model a bit messy, but interesting.
- The preference of 4 and 8 size brackets has been implemented by maximizing the number of brackets of size 4 and 8 (both have weight 1, the other bracket sizes have weight 0); this is the "z" variable. An alternative is to weight bracket size of 8 by 2 and size 4 of 1 (and all other weight 0) which thus prefer 8 size brackets over 4 size brackets.

Notes: 
- There are also some other constraints - implicit constraints and symmetry breaking - which tend to speed up the model, such as:

```
 sum(set_size) = n % implicit constraint

 x[1] = 1 % assign the first person to bracket 1
```

- The code also includes some stuff for randomized testing such as rand_int_array (MiniZinc don't have that as a built-in). That can be ignored.
- I don't know how large N can be in real life. Perhaps it's very large, then one have to add some more symmetry breaking etc or using another approach.

Here's an output from running the example given:

```
w: [100, 103, 105, 106, 110, 114, 120, 125]
z: 2
x: [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
set_size: [4, 4, 0, 0]
diffs: [6, 15, 0, 0]
mins: [100, 110, 0, 0]
maxs: [106, 125, 0, 0]
bracket 1: [100, 103, 105, 106]
bracket 2: [110, 114, 120, 125]
```

Here we see that two brackets of size 4 have the optimal value (z=2 since there are 2 size 4) as expected.

For another example with N=28, the model give this results ("w" is the array of 'random' weights).

```
w: [111, 109, 112, 146, 115, 103, 130, 145, 128, 127, 144, 114, 133, 126, 134, 133, 114, 134, 143, 116, 106, 104, 147, 110, 114, 102, 118, 130]
z: 7
x: [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 3, 5, 5, 3, 7, 7, 5, 7, 6, 7, 6, 6]
set_size: [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
diffs: [6, 18, 13, 18, 13, 19, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
mins: [109, 128, 103, 126, 134, 114, 102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
maxs: [115, 146, 116, 144, 147, 133, 110, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
bracket 1: [111, 109, 112, 115]
bracket 2: [146, 130, 145, 128]
bracket 3: [103, 114, 114, 116]
bracket 4: [127, 144, 133, 126]
bracket 5: [134, 134, 143, 147]
bracket 6: [133, 114, 118, 130]
bracket 7: [106, 104, 110, 102]
```

This is solved in about 0.7s by Gecode.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you @hakank! Interesting to see that you still had to define a max number of sets upfront.  I was having a hard time modeling this aspect of the problem.  You have been extremely helpful.  Thanks again!

Comment: Happy to be of some help, Alex. 

MiniZinc requires that all arrays have fixed sizes, so I defined it to be the max possible value (N div 2, the least allowed set size), in part for efficiency reason.

Answer (score 0):

Since you noted Java as a keyword, you might want to investigate the Java solvers, which should be able to handle partitioning problems:

- [OptaPlanner](http://www.optaplanner.org/)
- JaCop
- ECLiPSe CLP
- Choco
- JSR-331
- OR-tools (requires installation of non-JVM code)
- ...

Comment: How would an IDE like Eclipse solve the problem of finding such an algorithm? (apart from the editing aid that is)

Comment: I think that Geoffrey refer to ECLiPSe CLP, not the IDE. And I would add Google or-tools/Java to the list of Java solvers.

Comment: @hakank updated answer accordingly (feel free to edit further if desired :)

Comment: @hakank is OR-tools 100% pure Java (so can it be distributed as only jars without native jars)? Or let me rephrase that: does it work on any JVM without additional installments?

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet: or-tools is not pure Java. The engine is written in C++ so it must be installed as well.